# Помогите разобраться с префабами в unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Помогите!В юнити ,в скрипте я должен в игровом процессе создать префаб,он создаётся,но создаётся не в том месте где я хочу(я имею ввиду не в том месте в иерархии).Например я хочу что бы префабы появлялись в канвасе,или в каком-то объекте,но префабы появляются сами по себе (в иерархии).Так вот,как сделать так чтобы префабы,создавались там ,где я хочу(в любом месте иерархии)?

```
void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
    switch (gameObject.name) {
    case "plus_square":
        var child = Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        child.SetParent (parent, false);
        break;
    }
}
```

Что не так?Переменные я объявил

Comment: Добавте фрагмент кода, где з Вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

Comment: @0xdb и где то тут надо поставить так чтобы я сам решал где создавать префаб

Comment: @0xdb можете помочь?

Comment: @Антон например `public GameObject parent` - предок, который где-то назначается..... далее `var child = Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); child.SetParent(parent, false);`

Comment: Правте [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/688409/edit).  Ctrl-K -
 для формата как код блок.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 
`void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
  switch (gameObject.name) {
  case "plus_square":
   var child = Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
   child.SetParent (parent, false);
   break;
  }
 }`
не работает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @0xdb можете помочь?

Comment: Попробуйте может `child.transform.SetParent(parent, false)`

Comment: @AGS17 неработает

Comment: У вас есть уже один ответ, напишите - почему он не помог вам в решении?

Comment: @0xdb потому что этот код не работает

Comment: Какой код? Вы до сих пор не добавили код в вопрос.

Comment: @Антон 1) добавь весь код в вопрос. весь класс.. 2) объясни, где у тебя есть ссылка на `parent` где ты задаешь его 3) объясни в чем выражается `код не работает` 4) почему `child.SetParent`, а не `child.transform.SetParent`?

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Редактируйте старый

Answer (score 2):

Ну например использовать [SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

Comment: Это в языке c#?

Comment: @Антон да.  в *js* скорее всего будет `b.transform.parent = a.transform`, где `b` - ребенок, `a` - родитель

Comment: А в C#?Можете показать?

Comment: @Антон так вон же ссылка на документацию с примером `b.transform.SetParent(a, false);`, где `b` - ребенок, `a` - родитель

Answer (score 1):

```
    void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
    switch (gameObject.name) {
    case "plus_square":
        Transform child = (Instantiate (prefab, parent.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject).transfrom;
        child.SetParent (parent,true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Либо

```
void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
    switch (gameObject.name) {
    case "plus_square":
        Transform child = (Instantiate (prefab)).transfrom;
        child.SetParent (parent, true);
        child.localPosition=Vector3.zero;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `var child = Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, parent);` Где `parent` это `Transform`.