# Как сделать обьект дочерним при прикосновение!

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я хочу чтобы когда мой персонаж прикосался с другим обьектом, этот обьект становился дочерним обьектом моего персонажа.

Вот код:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Frends"))
    {
       //code
    }
}
```

Comment: А также этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257285/setparent-in-unity, этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688409/. И вообще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bunity3d%5D+SetParent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью метода **[SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)**

```
other.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
```